# How to set a Makefile variable from external shell call from the target

Tags: shell, makefile

I need to read a list of the files from some text file, line by line, then translate it to the sequence of `-a filename1 -a filename2 -a filename3`.
I've tried to do this, but looks like the syntax of the setting FILES variable is wrong in that context:

```
files_pack:
    @while read -r file; do \
         FILES += "-a $$file"; \
    done <$(LIST_FILE)
    some_util $(FILES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [Anton Kochkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720201/1566221), a simple solution which will work with any shell, but fails if filenames contain whitespace or metacharacters:

```
files_pack:
    some_util $(shell printf " -a %s" $$(cat $(FILES)))
```

This can be improved to handle filenames with whitespace or special characters other than apostrophes:

```
files_pack:
    some_util $(shell IFS="$$(printf '\n+')"; IFS="$${IFS%+}"; printf " -a '%s'" $$(cat $(FILES)))
```

The peculiar sequence of setting `IFS` to <kbd>newline</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and then removing the <kbd>+</kbd> is the only Posix-compatible way I know of to set `IFS` to a single newline which does not involve a command-line with a physical newline. (Simple command substitution deletes trailing newlines regardless of the setting of `IFS`.)

With bash, this can be simplified and made more robust, using the `%q` printf format (and some other bashisms to simplify):

```
files_pack: SHELL := /bin/bash
    some_util $(shell IFS=$$'\n'; printf " -a %q" $$(<$(FILES)))
```

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to handle also different file endings - `/r/n` and just `/n` in the file with the list?

Comment: @AntonKochkov: Sure, you just have to add `\r` to `IFS`. (Of course, that will also recognize `\r` by itself as a line-ending, but usually that's not a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Shell assignments cannot have spaces around the `=`/`+=`.

Also `$(FILES)` is going to be expanded by make. You want `"$${FILES[@]}"` there.

I also modified your code to use an array instead of a string so that files with spaces/etc. in the name can work correctly.

```
files_pack:
    @while read -r file; do \
         FILES+=(-a "$$file"); \
    done <$(LIST_FILE)
    some_util "$${FILES[@]}"
```

Though, as Jens pointed out this will not with with `/bin/sh` on many systems and would require telling make to use `/bin/bash` as the shell for this target:

```
files_pack: SHELL := /bin/bash
```

or globally:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Comment: `FILES+=` is valid shell syntax?

Comment: @Jens True. This would need `SHELL = /bin/bash` in the makefile to be guaranteed to work.

Comment: `+=` was added in `bash` 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

If the LIST_FILE has one file per line, and all you need to do is prepend each line with `-a`, then what you want is

```
files_pack:
       some_util $$(sed 's/^/-a /' $(LIST_FILE))
```

Comment: Adding single quotes to the line contents is likely a good idea also (in case they have spaces in the names) but that's not actually safe since they could also contain single quotes which would end the argument and re-introduce problems with spaces/arbitrary-command-execution/etc.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

`FILES=$(shell cat ${LIST_FILE)
 FILES_OPT=$(addprefix -a,${FILES})`

And this solution doesn't depend from bash, works with every generic shell, and doesn't require 'sed' to be installed.

Comment: It also doesn't/can't handle filenames with spaces in them.